# Is it possible to get the current test in setUp fixture?

Tags: php, phpunit, fixtures

I couldn't find any such thing, and I'm guessing it doesn't exist..

```
class Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function setUp() {
        echo $current_test; // Output a string "testOne"
    }

    public function testOne() {
        // This is the first test; before this test is ran setUp() is called.
        // The question is, is there any way to know within setUp() what the 
        // current test is?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$this->name` should contain the current testcase method name. You can access it (as David kindly pointed out) with `$this->getName()`.

Check out the API for TestCase at https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.6/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php. Skim over the properties and their comments to get an idea of what's available.

Comment: `$name` was changed to private, so you'll need to use `$this->getName()`.

Comment: Indeed, the source is the best way to find what's available. :)